# Increment Cell Hotkey

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a hotkey in google sheets to increment any cell +1 or -1?

I've seen many guides on click-drag patterns, creating buttons to increment a specific cell, but sometimes if you're doing inventory, it would be nice to increment rather than overwrite the value in the cell.

Comment: Is the cell you want to increment need to be able to be typed in? Provide a link to a google sheet with sample data, and desired output.

Comment: There is a help article about Google Sheets keyboard shortcuts. Have you already reviewed? Have you considered to create a macro?

Answer (score 3):

```
Tools -> Macros -> Record Macros
```

1. hit save
2. rename Untitled Macro to Add
3. make shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Shift+1
4. after hitting ok on the bottom left click edit script

replace add with the following function

```
function add() {
  var c = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getCurrentCell();
  c.setValue(c.getValue()+1);
};
```

Now when you press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+1 it will add 1 to the cell. Repeat the same steps but instead subtract and minus 1, if you don't like Ctrl+Alt+Shift+1 you can use a program like autohotkey to remap a key on your keyboard to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+1 etc.